# Matrix using only one column for header and row

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Let's say I have a list of names like this one in a csv:

```
Nom;Link;NonLink
Deb;John;
John;Deb;
Martha;Travis;
Travis;Martha;
Allan;;
Lois;;
Jayne;;
Brad;;Abby
Abby;;Brad
```

I imported it using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
file = np.genfromtxt('liste.csv', dtype=None, delimiter =';',skip_header=1)
```

Now, I'm isolating my first column:

```
Nom = np.array(file[:,0])
```

I would like to create a matrix using only this first column to get a result like this one:

```
      Deb    John    Martha    etc...   
Deb     0       0         0     ...
John    0       0         0     ...
Martha  0       0         0     ...
etc...
```

Is there a numpy function for that?

Edit: My end goal is to make a little program to assign seats at tables where people in Link must be seated at the same table and NonLink must not be at the same table.

Thank you,

Comment: Added pandas tag, might be helpful.

Comment: Could you add how the endgoal would look like for that sample case?

Comment: It's in the Edit part at the end of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas and create a dataframe using `Nom` variable.
Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0] * len(Nom)] * len(Nom), Nom, Nom)
print(df)
```